# CSS vertical alignment of :before pseudo element and td content

Tags: html, css, alignment, media-queries, pseudo-element

I've got a very specific problem within a web view I am creating for mobile devices. I have a `table` within the webview which is re-arranged vertically for smartphone displays. For the re-arrange, I hide the `table` head line and take the column name as `:before` pseudo element from a `data-label` attribute on the original html element.

Now the problem is, that the pseudo element and the `td` content won't align vertically, even though both elements are floated opposed. I am sure that the reason is the length of the text within the `td` element but I don't know why.

Heres a picture of whats happening:

[image: The alignment problem]

My html is processed like this:

[image: Processed HTML markup]

The computed css code is the following:

1. `td` Style

[image: td css style]

2. `:before` Style

[image: pseudo element css style]

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening and what I have to change to make it function like it's supposed to?

Best regards

Comment: Looks like you don't close the double quotes in the bottom two cells.

Comment: Hey, those double quotes are closed. I've checked it in the chrome developer. For no apparent reason there are some space in between which push the closing out of the screenshot. I removed them to test if those are the reason for the problem, but no they aren't.

Comment: We need the **actual** code...not images of it.

Comment: There is a reason I provided images. The actual code is razor .cshtml code which can not easily be added within a simple example fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself...

The problem was in fact the .cshtml razor syntax compilation.

Since those date fields were placed within a c# if-statement I formatted the code like usual:

```
@if(startDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
  <td class="ta-left" data-label="Start">@startDate</td>
}
```

The text identiation and the line breaks for clean code here were the problem.

The razor compiler inserted a break for those parts. The problem could be fixed using the following razor markup:

```
@if(startDate != DateTime.MinValue){<td class="ta-left" data-label="Start">@startDate</td>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are facing this problem is because you are using float style in td:before.

index.html

```
<table class="table table-hover theme-1">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <span>Table col</span>
       </td>                           
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                          
 </tbody>
```

Please put a **span** tag in the td cell and give it the max-width.Like this :

```
max-width: 50%;
display: block;
```

And in the before section add the remaining max-width.
Like this:

```
td:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "shaane shane";
        right: 0;
        max-width: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
```

P.S. Set it using **position** attribute please don't use **float**.

Comment: I'll try that and respond as soon as I verified it.

Comment: I've added the answer. There wasn't a problem with my css. It was a problem with the razor Syntax compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Set

`td {
  vertical-align: middle
}`

Comment: Tried that before, didn't affect the pseudo element. :/

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is razor syntax .cshtml code which makes it quite time consuming to provide a working fiddle with just html code. :/

Comment: Opss sorry any live link?

Comment: No sorry :/ I guess I just have to try the different options.

Comment: Try to use `flex` for align item middle properly